# With the new Guild Wars ability to have full hero teams, where can I find good non-elite builds for teams?

Tags: guild-wars

Can anyone tell me where to find good builds for a hero team (7 heroes) that don't rely on elite skills?

Comment: Why would you not want to use Elites? They are there to be helpfull. Or do you mean PvE skills? As heroes can't use these.

Comment: Heroes can use elite skills.

Comment: If you have no elite skills unlocked, you can always go unlock the skills on a pvp only character.  Your hero's can then use the skill!

Comment: which elite skills DO you have?

Comment: @yx_ burning arrow, barrage, word of healing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a very good reason to not use elites, you should never be without an elite on any skill bar.  If you simply do not have any elites unlocked yet, you should stick with henchmen and go capture some (or unlock via balthazar faction).

The only good hero builds I can think of that do not benefit greatly from having an elite is a minion master and a n/rt healer.

*updated after available elites are posted*

Barrage and word of healing are two very good elites, you can easily build a pretty straight forward woh healer monk with that for support purposes.  Barrage is also a great elite for a spliter/barrage ranger (assuming you have access to ritualist skills).

Here is a good hero party build designed around splinter/barrage:
Bring Acolyte Jin, Margrid, and Pyre, give them all distracting shot, barrage, volley, savage shot, lightning reflexes, res sig (or resurrection of choice), and put favorable winds on at least 2 of them.

Bring along either Razah or Xandra with max channeling and spliter weapon and some channeling spirits to spam.

Bring along a necro hero of choice with max death magic, 8 soul reaping, 10 channeling (backup splinter weapon), with bone minions, death nova, and bone fiends (great synergy with favorable winds)

Finally, bring along a woh hero and a protection henchie.

That should make a fairly formidable party for just about every none elite zone in the game.

Comment: I don't have many elite skills and I am only playing the game to get to 30 HoM points for GW2, so trying to do as little as possible.

Comment: 30 points is quite high, you'll not really be able to do 'little' to get to this point. I've been playing nearly 6 years and only have 22 points! Granted I'm not a hardcore grinder! The only real way you could achieve this in short notice is to buy weapons and minipets, which would net you a few points. Also buy armour sets.

Answer (score 0):

I use this page, 
http://www.gwpvx.com/Category:Great_working_hero_builds
http://pvx.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Great_working_hero_builds
I'm not sure which version of the site is more up to date :)

And I also download their template packs and unzip them into my templates folder. 
http://www.gwpvx.com/Build_Packs